# Change Imageview of Alertdialog as per the result

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to develop the UI in which user will touch the touch pad and if he is registered user of the system , he will be verified by my app. So to indicate that I want to change the fingerprint image by green (valid user) , red (invalid user). So I have created the `fragment` in which I am getting that result in following two methods

```
@Override
public void authenticate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "authoticate: ");
    result = "Yes";
    //customBuilder.setImage(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_pressed);//tried but not working

}

@Override
public void errorAuthenticate() {
    Log.d(TAG, "fail: ");
    result = "No";
    //  customBuilder.setImage(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_pressed_error);//tried but not working
}
```

Now in same `fragment` I have created the `CustomDialog` to show the above images which will be change dynamically. Code for CustomDialog class is given below

```
public class CustomDialog extends AlertDialog {

    public CustomDialog(Context context, int theme) {
        super(context, theme);
    }

    public CustomDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    /**
     * Helper class for creating a custom dialog
     */
    public static class Builder {

        private Context context;
        private String title;
        private int res;
        private String message;
        private String positiveButtonText;
        private String negativeButtonText;
        private View contentView;

        private DialogInterface.OnClickListener
                positiveButtonClickListener,
                negativeButtonClickListener;

        public Builder(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }


        public Builder setMessage(String message) {
            this.message = message;
            return this;
        }


        public Builder setMessage(int message) {
            this.message = (String) context.getText(message);
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the Dialog title from resource
         * @param title
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setTitle(int title) {
            this.title = (String) context.getText(title);
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the Dialog title from String
         * @param title
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
            return this;
        }
        public Builder setImage(int res){
            this.res = res;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set a custom content view for the Dialog.
         * If a message is set, the contentView is not
         * added to the Dialog...
         * @param v
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setContentView(View v) {
            this.contentView = v;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the positive button resource and it's listener
         * @param positiveButtonText
         * @param listener
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setPositiveButton(int positiveButtonText,
                                         DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
            this.positiveButtonText = (String) context
                    .getText(positiveButtonText);
            this.positiveButtonClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the positive button text and it's listener
         * @param positiveButtonText
         * @param listener
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setPositiveButton(String positiveButtonText,
                                         DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
            this.positiveButtonText = positiveButtonText;
            this.positiveButtonClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the negative button resource and it's listener
         * @param negativeButtonText
         * @param listener
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setNegativeButton(int negativeButtonText,
                                         DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
            this.negativeButtonText = (String) context
                    .getText(negativeButtonText);
            this.negativeButtonClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Set the negative button text and it's listener
         * @param negativeButtonText
         * @param listener
         * @return
         */
        public Builder setNegativeButton(String negativeButtonText,
                                         DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
            this.negativeButtonText = negativeButtonText;
            this.negativeButtonClickListener = listener;
            return this;
        }

        /**
         * Create the custom dialog
         */
        public CustomDialog create() {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // instantiate the dialog with the custom Theme
            final CustomDialog dialog = new CustomDialog(context,
                    R.style.Dialog);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.capture_finger_touch, null);
//            dialog.addContentView(layout, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
//                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            // set the dialog title
            ((ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImageResource(res);
            // set the confirm button
            if (positiveButtonText != null) {
                ((Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn))
                        .setText(positiveButtonText);
                if (positiveButtonClickListener != null) {
                    ((Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.btn))
                            .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    positiveButtonClickListener.onClick(
                                            dialog,
                                            DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                                }
                            });
                }
            } else {
                // if no confirm button just set the visibility to GONE
                layout.findViewById(R.id.btn).setVisibility(
                        View.GONE);
            }

            dialog.setView(layout);
            return dialog;
        }

    }

}
```

And I have used above CustomDialog by following way

```
public static String result = "No Found";


CustomDialog.Builder customBuilder = new CustomDialog.Builder(getActivity());
public void captureFingerPrintTouchCustom() {
    if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
        customBuilder.setImage(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_pressed);
    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
        customBuilder.setImage(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_pressed_error);
        //rl.startAnimation(animation);
    } else customBuilder.setImage(R.drawable.ic_fingerprint_for_capture);
    customBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK2", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialog = customBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Here as per the `result` value I want to change the image of customdialog.
capture_finger_touch.xml code is given below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/alert_dialog_size"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_background"
        android:padding="@dimen/view_internal_space">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/key_bg_square"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fingerprint_for_capture" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            style="@style/button_style"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/BTC_title_size"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But problem is that its not changing the image dynamically. CustomDialog is created like this,

[image: image is not changing as per the <code>result</code> value]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to extend `DialogFragment.class`, inflate there you layout and communicate with it in you `Activity` or `Fragment`

```
public class FingerprintDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private DialogFingerprintBinding binding;
private Listener listener;

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        listener = (Listener) context;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " implement Listener");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //if you use databinding 
    //binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()), R.layout.XXX, null, false);
    //binding.buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(this);
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.XXX, container, false);
   Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);

    getDialog().setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

    if (getDialog().getWindow() != null) {
        getDialog().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }

    //return binding.getRoot(); for binding
     return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button:
            listener.cancel();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public void changeImage(//posible resource) {
    //change Image here
}

public interface Listener {
    void cancel();
}
```

}

And then create instance of this dialog nad show it using method `DialogFragment#show`

Answer (score 0):

You need to setImageResource to ImageView as follows:

```
private fingerPrintImageView;
public CustomDialog create() {fingerPrintImageView = ((ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imgView)).setImageResource(res);}
public Builder setImage(int res){this.res = res;fingerPrintImageView.setImageResource(res); return this;}
```